# Highcharts customized chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, lines, axis-labels

I'm using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com) to develop a customized chart. Here is what I've gotten by my own [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sasantiago/Wqt9e/4/).
Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'area',
            inverted: true,
            height: 700,
            width: 780,
            marginRight: 20
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        colors: [
            '#828385',
            '#3AAFC1',
            '#F87D2A',
            '#80699B',
            '#3D96AE',
            '#DB843D',
            '#92A8CD',
            '#A47D7C',
            '#B5CA92'],
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ' '
        },
        subtitle: {
            style: {
                position: 'absolute',
                right: '0px',
                bottom: '10px'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            itemDistance: 30,
            x: 180,
            verticalAlign: 'top'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Label1", "Label2", "Label3", "Label4", "Label5", "Label6", "Label7", "Label8", "Label9", "Label10"],
            offset: -410,
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 0

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 1

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 2

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 3

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 4

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 5

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 5

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 6

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 7

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 8

            }, {
                color: '#A0A0A0',
                width: 1,
                value: 9

            }]
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Índice teste'
            },
            max: 100,
            min: 0,
        },
        plotOptions: {
            area: {
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            },
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            if (jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val() == 'Processo') {
                                jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val('Atividade');
                            } else if (jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val() == 'Atividade') {
                                jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val('Procedimento');
                            } else if (jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val() == 'Procedimento') {
                                jQuery('#type_group_name_hidden').val('Processo');
                            }
                            jQuery('#group_name_hidden').val(this.category);
                            requestAjaxChart('processos', buildProcessos);
                        }
                    }
                },
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 1
                },
                threshold: 50
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Market",
            data: [46.503590664272934, 51.39078282828278, 56.89226932668327, 47.66801075268824, 46.82561768530563, 59.23058676654176, 51.08220338983055, 46.17849829351536, 55.84550063371354, 51.428756058158314]
        }, {
            name: "My network",
            data: [48.175, 27.159999999999997, 39.916666666666664, 38.6, 53.85, 38.949999999999996, 30.4, 51.9, 33.519999999999996, 54.7875]
        }, {
            name: "Avg",
            data: [70, 80, 65, 75, 85, 82, 72, 69, 71, 58]
        }]
    });
});
```

Even it looks pretty good, it's not exactly what the client desire. I need to do some changes as described bellow:

1. Remove all the vertical lines on xAxis. As my chart is a inverted one, I couldn't figure out how to remove them.
2. On the xAxis values (0 - 100), remove the intermediaries values (10, 20, 30, ...) keeping just the first and last value (0, 100)
3. Move the yAxis labels upon the horizontal lines
4. Make clickable the points behind the overflowed chart area

I've tried almost all configuration options but with no success.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some answers :

1) See from docs [gridlineWidth](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.gridLineWidth) property.

2) See from docs [tickPositions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions) property.

3) Another docs [labels.y](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.y) property.

4) Not possible, even if it's SVG/VML it still is HTML, you can't make clickable DIV which is positioned behind another one.

Comment: I would kiss you right now! Thank you so much. Just one more point. Could you check my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sasantiago/Wqt9e/5/). Is there a way to remove that vertical line?

Comment: Sure, add `lineWidth: 0`, for xAxis.

Comment: Nice! Worked perfect! Thanks!

Comment: just one more question. Do you know if is there a way to stretch the text of the yAxis label along its line?

Comment: Could you create simple mockup for this? Like image or so.

Comment: Here is what I need - [img](http://imageshack.us/a/img706/996/mtnf.png)
And here is what I have - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sasantiago/Wqt9e/12/)

Comment: You were so close! Use `labels.style.width` instead of `labels.width` ;) See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wqt9e/13/

Comment: Nice! Worked perfect!